# Nested table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, nested, ordbms

I have 2 tables. USER table with all personal details and TWEETTABLE with all  tweets from user's timeline retrieved through twitter api

**User table**

```
  id|twitter_user_name|firstname|lastname|email
 -----------------------------------------------
  1 |  @johnsmith     |john     |smith   |js@gmail.com
```

**tweettable**

```
name|scr_name|tweets      |created_at_ |followers_count
----------------------------------------------------------
CNN |CNN     |*tweet text*| 14nov 12:32|   38713286
```

What i actually actually want is:

```
     id|            twitter_details                             |
  -----|------------------------------------------------------- |
       |name |scr_name|tweets      |created_at_ |followers_count|
       | ----|--------|------------|------------|--------------
     1 |  CNN|CNN     |*tweet text*| 14nov 12:32|   38713286    |
   ----|------------------------------------------------------
     2 |  BBC|BBC     |*tweet text*| 14Nov 16:43|   38713254    |
   ----|-----|--------|------------|------------|---------------|------
     3
```

that is, a table inside a column. Column 1 will have the user id and column two with all of his corresponding twitter timeline details.I can probably do this in oracle by doing this:

```
CREATE TYPE tweet_typ AS OBJECT
( 
 name VARCHAR2(20),
 scr_name VARCHAR2(25),
 tweets text,
 created_at timestamp;
 followers count VARCHAR2(25)
 )
MEMBER PROCEDURE display_details (SELF IN OUT
twitter_typ )
);
```

and use this inside the twitter_details column as a nested table

```
CREATE TABLE TWEETTABLE
( id INT,
  twitter_details tweet_typ
   );
```

And then insert

```
 INSERT INTO TWEETTABLE
  VALUES ( 1,twitter_typ (--extracted values goes here--));
```

But Mysql does not allow nested tables.So how can I define tweettable as an object and making it a nested table inside the column twitter_details in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, but you can do the way everybody does. Just define

```
tweettable
```

as

```
tweetID | userID |name|scr_name|tweets      |created_at_ |followers_count
----------------------------------------------------------
  1          1    CNN |CNN     |*tweet text*| 14nov 12:32|   38713286
```

you add 2 columns. One (can be autoinc) tweetID and one userID, related to the user who twitted.

Then you get your result with join

```
select * from user u join tweettable t where u.id = t.userID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use cross-table. For example "users_tweets".
table structure:

```
user_id | tweed_id
```

Where `user_id` - it is `id` from 'user_table' and 'tweet_id' it is 'id' from `tweettable`

or

```
user_id | tweet_name
```

Other way - convert twitter_details to string:

```
$strDetails = json_encode($twitter_details)
```

and insert this string `$strDetails` to database